# displaying extra > on option tag

Tags: jsp

I am using the option tag insides the input tag due to my requirement like below.

But the result is showing extra > .

```
<input type="checkbox" <option></option>>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want the option tag to do? Just use your `<input type="checkbox" />` tag and you'll have a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was trying to use the value of option tag when the checkbox is clicked. It was so simple when I used to set value of input tag instead of using extra option tag value.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="${myvalue}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if [checkbox type](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) for input tag has an option attribute..

Your option attributes there means nothing, just try to remove the option tag.. It will show your checkbox also..